# Selected Value Not Displayed in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails. I am trying to select a value from a drop down menu. My code is as follows

```
<%=  form_tag({:action=> "abcd"}) do %>                                
     <%= select_tag(:select_insert_type,options_for_select([1,2],params[:select_insert_type]))%>
<%=end>
```

but the above code does not select any value. I looked at the corresponding HTML but there is no selected value there either. I think it should store the selected value in a `params` variable and the correct value should be selected when I pass it to the `select_tag`.

I guess this may be silly question, but I spent hours and I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: What is `params[:select_insert_type]` set to?  One thing to watch out for is strings versus integers: for example `params[:select_insert_type]` might be `"1"` rather than `1`.  Try changing `[1,2]` to `["1", "2"]`

Comment: @user3793396 Your code works for me, must be something else that is going wrong. What is the controller doing that receives this form?

Answer (score -1):

Since the contents of `params` is all strings (Rails is cheating here) you would have to make sure your types match. Since you specify your options as `Fixnum` (or `int`) you should convert your param value too. Since `1 == "1"` yields `false` you should try `params[:select_insert_type].to_i` as your value and the helper will probably comply.

Comment: `1` and `"1"` will select the same item.